# Distribution on number of revisits in past $k$ steps of Markov chain

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains, markov-process

Consider a finite-state Markov chain with transition matrix $P$. The chain starts in a state chosen uniformly over all the states and runs indefinitely from there.

We're going to examine only the $k ≥ 0$ most recent steps of the chain. In particular, we will consider the number of states that appear $0, 1,\ldots, k$ times in those most recent $k$ steps. Let's define a vector $C = [c_0, c_1, \ldots,c_k]$ whose $i$-th element is the number of states that have been visited $i$ times within the past $k$ steps.

For example, if $k = 4$, if the state space is $1, 2, \ldots, 10$, and if the chain is $$1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3$$ then $c = [7, 2, 1, 0, 0]$.

What is the expected value of $C$ and, ideally, how is $C$ distributed?

Comment: I doubt this question has a nice answer even if you add irreducible + aperiodic assumptions unless the uniform distribution is a stationary distribution of the chain. If the chain is irreducible and aperiodic, asymptotically, the chain spends its fraction of its time in each state as given by the stationary distribution. How quickly these asymptotics become good is dependent on things like Dobrushin's coefficient of ergodicity.